# Taylor Inequality Error Bound Size

Tags: taylor-expansion

The formula for Taylor's inequality is given by:
$$|R_n(x)|\le \frac {M}{(n+1)!}|c-a|^{n+1}$$
Why does changing the value of $|c-a|$ change the size of the error bound? Can someone provide a simple example that demonstrates this?

Comment: Because Taylor expansion uses only local information (derivatives at one point) so it will deteriorate as you move away from that point.

Comment: The simplest example is the $0$th-order Taylor approximation of a linear polynomial. Or, a little bit less trivially, the $1$st-order Taylor approximation (which is the tangent line approximation) of a quadratic polynomial.